# GUI update from another thread

Tags: multithreading, user-interface

I have some experience with Dot.Net and Android. In both cases the GUI can only be updated
from its own thread, i.e. updating the GUI directly from another thread leads to an exception.

I am wondering if this happens with all programming languages and frameworks. Or are
there frameworks/programming languages where the GUI can be updated from a different thread?

Comment: I've seen some claims, none of them substantiated.  While it is *very* difficult to make a large chunk of code thread-safe, the ultimate problem always is that it is never just that code that matters.  Programmers write code to make the UI do something *different*.  That code is just never thread-safe and nobody that creates UI libraries wants to support that kind of code.  So "no" is the easy and supportable answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are most UI frameworks single threaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544447/why-are-most-ui-frameworks-single-threaded)

Comment: Thanks, I could found another similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772658/why-is-a-single-threaded-model-used-to-update-the-ui-as-main-thread?lq=1