# How can I check if this check box is enabled from another method in Java?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

What I am trying to do is check if a check box is enabled from another method that is also running on another thread. I am fairly new to Java so I apologise in advanced if my code isn't how Java is usually written (or if it is written badly).

So I've made a method that created a iframe then adds a check box to it. I've removed the part which creates the jframe just to keep my code minimal - you can see it below:

```
private void initialize() {
    chckbxEnabled.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    chckbxEnabled.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    chckbxEnabled.setBounds(98, 123, 81, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxEnabled);
}
```

I've then created a new method in a new thread and called it from another method which I haven't shown here.

```
static Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void getPing() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(chckbxEnabled.isEnabled());
        if(chckbxEnabled.isEnabled()) {] // Part I am having trouble with
            String apiKey = "exmapleApiKey";
            URL url = new URL("http://example.com/ping.php?mode=get&apikey="+apiKey);
            URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
   public void run() {     
       try {
            getPing();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
    });
}
```

As you can see I am trying to access `chckbxEnabled.isEnabled()`. This worked because just after I made my main class I added `private static JCheckBox chckbxEnabled = new JCheckBox("Enabled");`. So I can access it but it always returns `true` when I print it even though the check box is sometimes checked.

So my question is what is a better way of doing this as I expect that way I have experimented with is 'messy' and not the way it should be done?

Comment: `isSelected()` ?? `isEnabled()` is true because you haven't disabled it

Comment: @FastSnail What do you mean? When I disable the checkbox it is disabled isn't it? :)

Comment: how did you desabled it?by unchecking??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up methods:

[isEnabled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isEnabled--) is for checking if the user can interact with the user (think greyed out elements)

[isSelected](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected--) is what you are looking for (check for the checkmark inside the box). You might want to take a look at [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) ([example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CheckBoxItemListener.htm))

Also: keep in mind that you can draw to the api only form the gui thread.

---

**Update:**
So: most gui frameworks allow only one thread to draw the gui, since synchronisation is very complex. Therefore most of swing is not thread safe. A good answer outlining this (actually related to swing), can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5544714/258418)

> [Quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.htm):
>
> A note on thread safety: It may seem strange that such an important
>   part of the Java platform is not thread safe. It turns out that any
>   attempt to create a thread-safe GUI library faces some fundamental
>   problems. For more on this issue, see the following entry in Graham
>   Hamilton's blog: MultiThreaded toolkits: A failed dream?

Given that we have to draw the gui from a single thread, what does this mean?
Update operations, i.e. changing a labels text should not be done from a thread you spawned, but should be done from the main thread that runs your gui code (in swing it is called [event dispatch thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)([in the swing trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)).
A tutorial on how to have worker threads that update the gui can be found i.e. [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/multi-threading-java-swing). the basic idea is to have a backgound thread do the calculations and return the result. There is [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to help with this. The gui thred will then update the gui.

A introduction to concurreny and swing is i.e. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Thank you. I feel really stupid but this worked. Could you explain what you mean about only being able to draw to the API from the GUI thread? As I said I'm new to Java so I would appreciate it if you could explain it to me. Thank you :)