# Why is not Swing "thread safe"?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, theory

In the final minutes of a Java lesson about threads, our professor suggested us to pay specific attention when developing complex Swing-based applications, since `Swing` is not thread-safe. Is there any specific reason behind this? `Swing` is not thread safe due to a design decision, or due to software limitations?
Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: See also [*java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater explained*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22534356/230513).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javin Poul's programming blog [Java Revisited](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/) has [a great blog post](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-swing-is-not-thread-safe-in-java-Swingworker-Event-thread.html) about this:

> **Why Swing is not thread-safe in Java?**
>
> It's the decision taken by there designer, at that time. Since making an API thread-safe takes a lot of work, and it's often based upon benefit you get. Since GUI screens are mostly updated in response of user action e.g. when user click a button, and since events are handled in the same Event dispatcher thread, it's easy to update GUI on that thread. It's very rare, when an update request for GUI comes from a different thread e.g. may be once a network request is complete or a file is loaded.

Comment: The blog post solved all my doubts and was very detailed, great

Answer (score 5):

Most, if not all, GUI toolkits are not thread-safe (Qt, Swing, Winforms...). Creating a thread-safe GUI toolkit would add too much unneccesary complexity. In most cases, it is sufficient to create 
a quick event handler.

For instance, we have a button that calculates 
a week day 40 days from today, converts Celsius temperature to Fahrenheit, or computes the sum of provided values. All these operations can be calculated fairly quickly. If Swing was thread-safe, these calculations would be placed inside separate threads, which would be clearly an overkill. So instead of this, we put only long-running tasks into threads, such as burning a DVD, calculating a very complex task, downloading a huge file etc.

See this answer:
[Why are most UI frameworks single threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544447/why-are-most-ui-frameworks-single-threaded)