# Forcing EDT Thread for Swing Libraries

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

All GUI related code should only be executed from the [`EDT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread). In `Android` development, something like this seems to be enforced kind of so you'll get an exception if you do e.g. make a network call in the main thread. However, for developing `Java` desktop application, there is no such thing. It is easy to forget about the `EDT` and still executing GUI code in another thread. This can cause weird glitches/bugs because [`Swing` is not thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306022/why-is-not-swing-thread-safe). Is there a way to strongly enforce the usage of the `EDT` for every GUI code by default similar to how `Android` is more strict? I do not want to manually check everything and instead get an exception if the `EDT` usage recommendation is violated. I'm using [`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

In terms of Java code, something like the following could be inserted automatically for every Swing library method:

```
if(!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("EDT property violated");
}
```

Any way to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ThreadCheckingRepaintManager, see here:
[ThreadCheckingRepaintManager](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=RomRaider-master/src/main/java/com/romraider/util/ThreadCheckingRepaintManager.java)

You can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(new ThreadCheckingRepaintManager(true));
        //Create your UI here
    }
```

Now you will get an info in the console whenever there is a EDT problem.