# Why my rectangle shape is so small in java graphics 2d

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

So I am new in java graphics and I am creating a program that will show a rectangle. But when I run my program it only show like a small box and not the rectangle. I don't really know why it is happening.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsEditor{

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        
        frame.setSize(1280, 720);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(rectangle);
        
    }
    
}
```

This is my rectangle class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Rectangle extends JPanel implements Shape {
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 130);
    }

}
```

This is my shape interface:

```
import java.awt.*;

public interface Shape {
    void paintComponent(Graphics g);
}
```

Comment: set the preferred size for your new panel and pack the frame after you add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GraphicsEditor {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(rectangle);
        frame.pack();
        // center frame on screen
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    
}
class Rectangle extends JPanel {
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 130);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }
}
```

A couple of things.

- you don't need the interface.
- unlike components, just painting a picture doesn't affect the layout manager, so the panel will be reduced to it's default size with out regard to any painting.
- so you need to override `getPreferredSize()` in your JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, you should set the preferred size of both your `panel` and `rectangle` to your desired size, and then pack the frame, like:

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
rectangle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
frame.pack();
```

Otherwise your LayoutManager (when not specified it defaults to `FlowLayout`) will handle your rectangle the way it wants. So another way would be learning about [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html), and using your desired one.

As a side note, I would like to make some suggestions to your code. Remember, [Swing is not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306022/why-is-not-swing-thread-safe), so place your code inside an `invokeLater()` call, such as:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

            frame.setSize(1280, 720);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            rectangle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

            frame.add(panel);
            panel.add(rectangle);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Also, calling `frame.setVisible(true)` should be called after adding your components.

Comment: The solution by WJS is preferable. Don't use setPreferredSize(). Each component should determine its own preferred size by overrring the getPreferredSize() method.

Comment: Yes, I think either will work out for OP, but WJS's solution should be preferred, I only noticed after reading his reply