# I am creating a tkinter gui, and i need to make it a thread. But the thread doesn't work

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am creating a chinese checkers AI. I want to make the board, and check the mouse position meanwhile. I decided to use multithreading:

```
from tkinter import *
from pyautogui import *
from threading import *

def create_board():
    #a lot of tkinter stuff
def check_mouse:
    if position()[0] > 390 & position()[0] < 455:
        print("mouse detected")

board = Thread(target=create_board)

board.start()
```

But when I run it in terminal, I get:

```
2018-11-11 16:50:55.129 python[27074:8053445] WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future. Called from (
    0   AppKit                              0x00007fff44af22e3 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 386
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff44aef68c -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1488
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff44aef0b6 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 45
    3   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000101319426 TkMacOSXMakeRealWindowExist + 742
    4   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000101318ffc TkWmMapWindow + 60
    5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000101261930 Tk_MapWindow + 192
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010126b541 MapFrame + 65
    7   libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x000000010119cc71 TclServiceIdle + 161
    8   libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x000000010117a39d Tcl_DoOneEvent + 397
    9   _tkinter.cpython-37m-darwin.so      0x000000010108a88e _tkinter_tkapp_mainloop + 286
    10  python                              0x000000010098eba6 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 230
    11  python                              0x000000010099bae4 _PyMethodDescr_FastCallKeywords + 84
    12  python                              0x0000000100acf32e call_function + 382
    13  python                              0x0000000100accd19 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45065
    14  python                              0x0000000100ac0a42 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 418
    15  python                              0x000000010098ea73 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
    16  python                              0x0000000100acf265 call_function + 181
    17  python                              0x0000000100accdaf _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45215
    18  python                              0x000000010098e368 function_code_fastcall + 120
    19  python                              0x0000000100acd1c6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46262
    20  python                              0x000000010098e368 function_code_fastcall + 120
    21  python                              0x0000000100acf265 call_function + 181
    22  python                              0x0000000100accd19 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45065
    23  python                              0x000000010098e368 function_code_fastcall + 120
    24  python                              0x0000000100acf265 call_function + 181
    25  python                              0x0000000100accd19 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45065
    26  python                              0x000000010098e368 function_code_fastcall + 120
    27  python                              0x0000000100991782 method_call + 130
    28  python                              0x000000010098f1e2 PyObject_Call + 130
    29  python                              0x0000000100baf5cb t_bootstrap + 123
    30  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff747a133d _pthread_body + 126
    31  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff747a42a7 _pthread_start + 70
    32  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff747a0425 thread_start + 13
)
```

What happened? Is there something wrong with the tkinter window?

Comment: Don't use threading with Tkinter if you don't have to.  If you really have to, use Tkinter's TopLevel widget for your UI element, and implement your own event loop.  It's a nuisance, to be avoided if possible.

Comment: @rd_nielsen: the use of threads is completely unrelated to the use of `Toplevel`. The important thing with threads is that you can only access tkinter objects from a single thread.

Answer (score 3):

Tkinter (like almost all GUI frameworks I'm aware of), require that modifications to the GUI state happen on a particular thread. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544447/why-are-most-ui-frame-works-single-threaded) for more discussion on why. This doesn't mean that there can't *be* any other threads in your application- just that you can't modify the state of the GUI from those other threads.

If you *must* use other threads to keep long-running tasks from hogging the thread being used for the GUI, you can have worker threads that interact with the main thread via a `Queue`, as described [here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm).

I can't caveat enough that multithreading will multiply the complexity of your application by 10x (especially if you are new to concepts like `Queue`s). However, if you are unfamiliar with `Queue`s and their typical use in concurrent programming and still want to get started, a good place to begin is with the [producer/consumer pattern](https://stonesoupprogramming.com/2017/09/06/python-producer-consumer-with-queue/). For an even more foundational look at what the "queue" concept means in comp-sci, you can look at [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_queue.htm) which describes a queue and has you implement your own simple version of one.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm not good at python yet. I am, after all, in 5th grade. Can you explain to me what Queue is about?

Comment: In general, queues are a data structure (like a `list` or `dict` that hold objects), but they're made to work so that the order you place things in the queue is the order they get removed. Think of a checkout line at the store. The queue in `from queue import Queue` in python is designed with other tools for concurrent programming. In particular, it can "block" when you try to `get` from one thread while other threads are working to create things to put on the queue.

Comment: also added some useful references to the answer